# Passing Extras and screen rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation, extras

This kind of questions appear periodically. Sorry if this has been covered before, but I'm a newbie and couldn't find the appropriate answer. It deals with the correct implementation of communication between classes and activities.

I made a gallery app. It has 3 main activities: the `Main` one, to search for filenames using a pattern; a `Thumb` one, that shows all the images that matched the pattern as thumbnails in a gridview, and a `Photo` activity, that opens a full sized image when you click a thumb in `Thumbs`. I pass to the `Photo` activity via an `Intent` the filenames (an array), and the `position` (an `int`) of the clicked thumb in the gridview.

This third `Photo` activity has only one view on it: a `TouchImageView`, that I adapted for previous/next switching and zooming according to where you shortclick on the image (left, right or middle). Moreover, I added a longclick listener to `Photo` to show EXIF info.

The thing is working, but I am not happy with the implementation... Some things are not right.

One of the problems I am experiencing is that, if I click on the right of the image to see the next in the `Photo` activity, it switches fine (`position++`), but when rotating the device the original one at `position` appears.

What is happening is that `Photo` is destroyed when rotating the image, and for some reason it restarts again, without obeying `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, loading again the Extras (the `position` only changed in `Photo`, not on the parent activities).

I tried with `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`, but failed...

Of course I can do something contrived to save the `position` data, but there should be something "conceptual" that I am not understanding about how activities work, and I want to do this right.

Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong, which is the best method to implement what I want, and why?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code whatsoever (so please do so), I will ask the obvious: Did you override `onSaveInstanceState()`?

Comment: @A--C: Yes, I did. I wrote that above.

Comment: Well you said it's not obeying in onCreate() so maybe you're having issues with saving the bundle. Either way attach code.

Comment: @A--C: I wrote `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` as the first line in `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. This is what you were referring to?

Comment: No, I meant that to use your bundle you must first save your bundle. Gaurang's answer is what I was asking about. Do you override the method `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle)`? Also, in your `onCreate()` do you use the Bundle for anything else but calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` Just calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` won't do a thing.

Comment: I see!! I am beginning to understand now... I'll answer the code posted by Gaurang below. Thanks!!

Comment: @A--C: From your answer, I understand that using `Bundle`, `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` etc is useless unless you overwrite the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle ???)`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: All I'm saying is that if you have a nice saved Bundle, you actually have to use it. If all you call is `super.onCreate` then you are letting the superclass deal with the Bundle, but the superclass is limited, it does not know how to handle all your extra saved keys (such as position). Which is why after calling super.onCreate, you have to actually **access** the Bundle, find the saved position nd go on from there. You should definitely look at tutorials for this.

Comment: @A--C: Yes, I need to learn this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code to store the values for the activity

```
Long value;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle onOrientChange) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(onOrientChange);
    onOrientChange.putLong("myValue", value);  
}
```

And restore the values in onCreate():

```
public void onCreate(Bundle onOrientChange) {
  if (onOrientChange!= null){
   value = onOrientChange.getLong("myValue");
  }
}
```

Usually you restore your state in `onCreate()`. It is possible to restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState()` as well, but not very common. (`onRestoreInstanceState()` is called after `onStart()`, whereas `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`.

Use the put methods to store values in `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: I see... It turned out that I had no clue about how to use this savedinstance thing (I still don't have much yet...). So what I did was to change my `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and replace it by your `public void onCreate(Bundle onOreintChange)`, and adding the other code you suggested, and it seems it is working fine now. Now: is there a problem NOT to use a `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` at all? What I mean is that, if I don't override the `savedInstanceState` method, is it necessary to use `Bundle` at all? THANKS!!